# Код не работает когда идет команда $mysqli->query($sql);

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot

Я использую Telegram WebHook. У меня есть сайт на хостинге 000webhost.
Есть там же база данных, версия PHP 8.2. Домен добавлен к ВебХук  бот без базы данных работает
Подключаюсь к базе `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "pass", "dbname");`

использую запрос

```
sql =      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, balance, chat_id) 
                VALUES ('$username', '$firstName', '$lastName', $balance, $userId)";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Таблица создана

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    balance DECIMAL(10, 2),
    chat_id INT
);
```

Беру значения для базы данных

```
  $username = $update["message"]["from"]["username"];
    $firstName = $update["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
    $lastName = $update["message"]["from"]["last_name"];
    $userId = $update["message"]["from"]["id"]; // Добавлено получение ID пользователя
     $balance = 0.0; // Значение по умолчанию
```

и тут проблема - уменя бот не работает когда идет команда     `$mysqli->query($sql);`
Если удалить эту команду то бот работает и отправляет обратным сообщениям все данные пользователя правильно.
У меня нету возможности просмотра логов -  хостинг представляет такую возможность только для премиум тарифов
Как можно исправить это?

Comment: Если не работает SQL запрос, то при чем тут телеграм бот?

Comment: А не надо логов. Надо просто вместо `$mysqli->query($sql);` тупо сделать `echo $sql;` и посмотреть, что выведется...

Comment: @Akina это ж памятник, тьфу - бот, ему некуда выводить. А то что логи писать можно самому, клиент не догадывается.

Comment: Но ведь куда-то бот "отправляет обратным сообщениям все данные пользователя правильно" (что бы это не означало), и автор это даже видит...